# KDB : How to delete rows from the table which has empty value for one of the column

Tags: kdb

Tried the following, it didn't worked.

`delete from result where key like ""`

Comment: Can you give some more detail? e.g. what is the schema of `result` table? And what do you mean by "it didn't work" e.g. did it give an error or an unexpected result? Part of the issue may be that `key` is a keyword in kdb https://code.kx.com/q/ref/key/

Comment: @JonathonMcMurray key is of  symbol type. I get this error. `An error occurred during the execution of query. The server sent the response. par.` I believe this is parsing error sort of thing.

Comment: Errors are explained here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/errors/

`'par` means that you are trying to delete from a partitioned table, which won't work - you'll need to use `select` here & reverse the condition i.e. `select from result where not key like ""` - however, the column being named `key` will still cause problems, due to that being a keyword in kdb. Finally, note that an alternative for `not key like ""` with a symbol column would be ``key<>` ``